# SQL server sp_executesql query error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

While I am trying to execute the following query, I keep getting an error. I am fairly new to `sp_executesql` and have been trying to work around this error.
Any help is appreciated.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SET @db = 'db_1'                           -- line 29
SET @sql = N'SELECT *
FROM [metadata].[table_name] A
JOIN [linked_server].' + @db + '.sys.objects B ON A.Tablename = B.name
JOIN [linked_server].=' + @db + '.sys.columns C ON A.columnname = C.Name
    AND B.object_id = C.object_id
JOIN [linked_server].'+@db+'.sys.types D ON D.user_type_id = C.user_type_id
WHERE A.Channel =' + @db + 'AND CHECKSUM(CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.Datatype, 126), 
CONVERT(INT, A.Max_Length)) 
     <> CHECKSUM(CONVERT(VARCHAR, D.name, 126), CONVERT(INT, C.max_Length))'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

**Error**

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Here's your problem: `JOIN [linked_server].=' + @db`

Comment: `JOIN [linked_server].='  ` remove "="

Comment: use print command before exec to verify such errors. It usually a typo error

Comment: For this sort of problem, you should always *print* the SQL (instead of/as well as) trying to execute it. Even if you cannot spot the error (you should be able to), it helps to include the final result in your question here, rather than forcing us to run the code ourselves to see what it produces.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is very correct. When you print out the query, you can clearly see there is a space missing. You only need to add a space in the where clause before the 'AND'. That is it really.

Comment: Yes, I get the point. thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in `JOIN [linked_server].=' + @db` and `WHERE A.Channel =' + @db + 'AND` 
please check this it will work

```
 DECLARE @db VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

    SET @db = 'db_1'
    SET @sql = N'SELECT *
    FROM [metadata].[table_name] A
    JOIN [linked_server].' + @db + '.sys.objects B ON A.Tablename = B.name
    JOIN [linked_server].' + @db + '.sys.columns C ON A.columnname = C.Name
        AND B.object_id = C.object_id
    JOIN [linked_server].'+@db+'.sys.types D ON D.user_type_id = C.user_type_id
    WHERE A.Channel = ' + @db + ' AND CHECKSUM(CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.Datatype, 126), 
    CONVERT(INT, A.Max_Length)) 
         <> CHECKSUM(CONVERT(VARCHAR, D.name, 126), CONVERT(INT, C.max_Length))'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```